# Unit Testing Initialising storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, unit-testing, storyboard

There are quite a few resources on unit testing whether just purely logical or application level, I am currently working trying to test a `UITableViewCell` that has IBOutlets within a storyboard and as a few posts have confirmed if i wish to instantiate the storyboard and then the view controller that contains the cell. So you have to go through a few steps to make sure the storyboard and following elements load properly with their IBOutlets like so

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testTableViewController"];
[self.vc performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

followed by this code to get a `UITableViewCell` from the `UITableViewController`

```
[self.vc setTableViewData:@[@1].mutableCopy];
[self.vc.tableView reloadData];
[self.vc.tableView layoutIfNeeded];

SUT = [self.vc.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"More Menu Cell"
                                         forIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

and this produces a cell however for me the first breakpoint i have inside the system under test, seems to indicate that the IBOutlets have loaded, however when i actually go to assert anything, they all of a sudden disappear one me...

either references are disappearing for no reason or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have made a few discoveries which i will share here, one of them was a solution to my issue whereas originally this question was one small symptom I was attempting to fix of a larger problem.

The larger problem was, I was testing some UITableViewCells, but unfortunately their IBOutlets which where connected from the storyboard where always nil, which led me to attempt messing with how the system under test should be initialised.

I also found mixed results for using `[self.vc performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];` as sometimes i would still have to call `view` or `viewDidLoad` for it to initialise properly. So then i did away with it entirely nd just call `view` and it seems to work fine.

However my cells still had nil outlets, despite my changes above. After rummaging around the internet a bit i discovered that, you should only be using `[self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MytableViewcell"];` **if it hasent been created created in a storyboard as a prototype cell.** It looks like it already does this for you and attempting to do it again breaks the `IBOutlets`.

Another small discovery was attempting to test a `UIViewController` of mine by setting it up like such

```
MyViewController *SUT = [MyViewController new];
[SUT view];
```

now although this initialises, again there seems to be some missing steps since this class exists in the storyboard, therefore i recommend the following

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SUT = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"My Table VC"];
[SUT view];
```